# Getting exception while adding images to listview to display using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have been working on wpf to make a image slider.
I have used ListView to diplay list of images and an Image Controller to Preview it.
Everything Works fine but when I load images more than 100, I get an unhandled exception like (thread currently not...Stack etc) something like that,I don't remember it properly.
Loading more than one hundred images makes the WPF Application slower and slower along the PC.
So please help me How can I overcome the problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Thread or Dispatcher when loading large number of images. also you can use BackgroundWorker for Async load.

```
  public LoadImages()
    {
   BackgroundWorker BWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        BWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BWorker_DoWork);
        BWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += 
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        BWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }

   void BWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmap = e.Result as BitmapSource;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal 
                (ThreadStart)delegate()
            {
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Source = bitmap;
                background.Child = image;
             });
    }

    void BWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmapSource = IMAGEFROMFILE;
        e.Result = bitmapSource;
     }
```

also you can user BitmapDecoder for height and width to reduce the size on the load time.

Comment: ok this is the solution for efficiency of program but how can I overcome memory Issues?
I have to load higher number if images to be shown to the user via listview in order to select one of it.

Comment: you should always use Using statement , GC will automatically clean the memory.